# Formatação CSS para geração de PDF

Tags: css3, pdf

Estou usando um loop para gerar um arquivo PDF. Cada iteração do loop deve gerar uma página do PDF.

O problema é que sempre está saindo uma página em branco no final do PDF gerado. Sei que esta página está saindo porque estou usando a propriedade CSS

```
page-break-after:always
```

Se eu tirar o `always`, a quebra de página não fica correta. Como posso resolver?

O HTML

```
@foreach($provas as $p)
    <div class="page-break">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="text-center">DNA Prova</h3>
            </div>
         </div>
          <Restante do conteúdo da página>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

O CSS

```
.page-break{
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Comment: Você escreveu certo ? É `always`.

Comment: Verdade, escrevi certo no código errei aqui. Obrigada

Comment: Você tentou usar `auto` ?

Comment: Tentei. Como disse, se usar qualquer coisa diferente do always, a quebra de página fica errada

Comment: Como está seu HTML ? Pode postar ?

Comment: colocar `auto` não resolve?

Comment: @DiegoSouza, editei a pergunta e coloquei o código

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues se eu usar o auto, a quebra de página fica errada.

Comment: Faz um CSS assim:
`.page-break:last-of-type{
    page-break-after: auto;
}`

Comment: Não deu certo, a página não quebra no lugar certo

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>  
            .page-break {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: always;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="page-break">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="text-center">DNA Prova1</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>            
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Conteudo 1</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="page-break">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="text-center">DNA Prova2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Conteudo 2</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="page-break">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="text-center">DNA Prova3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Conteudo 3</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não dá certo, desconfigura a página

Comment: Editei, pode conferir?